# Why would cause a .map to log to the console but not the actual view

Tags: javascript, react-native

For some reason in the below, only the first static **Text** tag renders to the screen without anything in the map function of the following:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
 <Text>Test for {this.props.active_test.name} - {this.props.active_question.text}</Text>

    {
        this.props.active_question.answers.map((a, i) => {
            <Text>{a.answer}</Text>
        })
     }
</View>
```

However, replacing the **Text** tag below with a console log logs this fine:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
 <Text>Test for {this.props.active_test.name} - {this.props.active_question.text}</Text>

    {
        this.props.active_question.answers.map((a, i) => {
            { console.log(a.answer) }
        })
     }
</View>
```

What would cause this behaviour? I have tried adding a key to both the Text wrapper and the View and still nothing.

Comment: You have to a return a component i.e. `map((a, i) => { return (<Text>{a.answer}</Text>); })` or even shorter: `map((a, i) => (<Text>{a.answer}</Text>))`.

Comment: You either need to remove the wrapping `{ ... }` OR `return <Text...`.

Comment: You forgot return in `map` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you arent returning anything.
You can fix it by

```
this.props.active_question.answers.map((a, i) => <Text>{a.answer}</Text>)
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful to know the difference in the single line return. Coming from Python these curly brackets are killing me

Comment: Indeed, switching from different language, things can be super confusing. I am trying to teach myself GOLang, same position as you. :P

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the execution in map wrapped with curly braces you need to return it. Or, you can not wrap the block and it will automatically return.

Do this

```
        this.props.active_question.answers.map((a, i) => {
            return <Text>{a.answer}</Text>
        })
```

Or this

```
        this.props.active_question.answers.map((a, i) => <Text>{a.answer}</Text>)
```